# MySQLDump Not Exporting Data or Structure

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I'm trying to dump a copy of my database to make sure that I have the proper permissions to do so, and to make sure that the backup strategy will work moving ahead. The problem that i am running into is that I am unable to create a dump file. Each time I attempt to do so, it simply returns to me the following:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.32, for Linux (i686)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: dbname
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.5.32

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2013-12-18 10:34:02
```

The command I am running is:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --flush-logs --single-transaction --master-data=2 --delete-master-logs --databases dbname > ./Back_Up_Test`date +%Y_%m_%d`.sql.bak
```

I attempted to add in 2>Error.err at the end of the command to check what error existed, but it didn't seem to generate any errors for me, as the file was size 0. With that, the user who I am attempting to run this at, at the moment, is root, and has full privileges on everything.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD *password* WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbname`.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                               |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What has me confused is the fact that the command works perfectly fine in Dev, but in this Test environment, backup simply refuses to be created for whatever reason. The folder should have proper permissions, as the file ends up existing in the directory with the proper name, it simply doesn't have the structure nor the data inside of it.

**Update:**
I've now tried it with --all-databases as an option, and it returned the exact same file size and contents as it did previous. I am uncertain as to what the cause is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the answer after a few hours of testing. When I originally started this, the MySQL server was updated sometime in the past, and therefore required that I had to run `/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p` to get proper privileges back to root user. After doing so, it allowed me to add privileges to other users. I did the customary/obligatory `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after this.

The actual solution was as follows:

After attempting to dump various different databases, all databases at once, etc, I simply became frustrated and rebooted the service itself. In doing so, I then attempted to perform the command exactly as it existed previously. At which point, mysqldump indeed did actually create the necessary file, with the necessary structure. I am unsure as to why I required a reboot of the service after everything - quite possible mysql_upgrade requires it after execution. But, should you find yourself in a position similar to this, I would suggest that you run through the following steps:

```
1. My first suggestion would simply be to check your privileges on the account that you are attempting to create the dump from, and verify that it has the necessary privileges.
2. If the Privileges match up with what is expected/necessary, then flush the privileges to make sure they have taken.
3. If you are still unable to create an mysql dump at this point, then restart the service.
```

Rather than deleting this question since the solution is so simple, I'm going to leave this up simply because this question seems to be asked somewhat often, especially in regard to PHP scripts/automation, and the questions I found didn't often have answers.

Hopefully this helps anyone else that has this issue.